# How to create a custom home page in XMLUI mirage 2 theme?

Tags: dspace

all I am working on DSpace 1.6 with XML UI mirage 2 theme, the default installation work fine,  I also know about the overlaying the styles in Mirage 2 theme by placing files in

`dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2` themes.

Generally, What I need is to modify a homepage, so that I can put latest and trending items in a homepage as a banner as shown in world bank home page as shown below.

[image]

Comment: I don't know who down vote this? If the person thinks this is really a stupid question please write in a comment below why this is a stupid question?

Comment: Are you attempting to add this content to the main page of the repository, or are you attempting to add this to a community/collection home page?  The community/collection pages allow you to insert custom html into a description.

Comment: Since this question is so specific to DSpace, I recommend removing the other tags from your question.  A reviewer who is not familiar with DSpace would likely be confused by the question.  I suspect that is why your question was down-voted.

Comment: @terryweb I am trying to add in a dspace homepage. What I really want  is, query the solr for instance, top 10 download items and populate them in a home page using xmlui.

Comment: Perhaps this [link](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Solr#Solr-QueryingSolrfromXMLUI) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following file is used to set content for the home page for an XMLUI site.  Editing this file might resolve your issue.

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/news-xmlui.xml

Comment: @terryweb I am trying to add in a dspace homepage. What I really want is, query the solar for instance, top 10 download items and populate them in a home page using XML UI.

Answer (score 0):

@psycho3
The basis for this can be found in later versions of DSpace, starting from version DSpace 4 I believe.
Check out a class called "SiteRecentSubmissions". https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/discovery/SiteRecentSubmissions.java

What this class does is add the latest submitted items to the frontpage.
You could create a new kind of class that finds the top downloaded items and adds them to the body of that new class.

But, that being said, this might be more difficult since you are using a Dspace 1.6 and there might be some serious limitations involved in terms of querying solr on the fly etc.

(Also, how did you manage to set up a DSpace 1.6 with a functional Mirage2 if I might ask?)

Comment: I just follow the installation instruction step by step and it did work.

Comment: Are you a 100% sure you are using a DSpace 1.6  (Check the pom of the "DSpace Parent Project" for the DSpace version)? 
+ Could you link me to the instructions you followed? (I'm guessing https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/dspace-5_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2)
1: I highly suspect simply following those steps on an old DSpace amounts to nothing.
2: It would make a big difference in your favour if you were on a higher version of Dspace.